# Display only difference in nested dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, difference

The data is coming from a database and from a csv file.
I have to compare them as fast as possible and update the database table by the corresponding value.
Let's suppose the dict d1 is coming from the database as d2 from in input file.
The main key is a primary key in the db. (here 1 and 2)

```
d1[1] = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
d1[2] = {'a': 11, 'b': 21}
```

Now is coming the data from the input file:

```
d2[1] = {'b': 10, 'a': 20}
d2[2] = {'b': 21, 'a': 19}
```

As you can see all values are different for the key 1 and only the value of 'a' is different for the key 2.
I have the following query:

```
print({o: ({b: d2[o][b]}) for o in d1.keys() for b in d2[o].keys() if d1[o][b] != d2[o][b]})
```

Expected result would be:

```
{1: ({'a': 20}, {'b': 10}), 2: {'a': 19}}
```

Instead of the this I have this result (I do not have all the modified values listed for 1):

```
{1: {'a': 20}, 2: {'a': 19}}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest a list comp in your dict comp.

```
{o: [{b: d2[o][b]} for b in d2[o].keys() if d1[o][b] != d2[o][b]] for o in d1.keys()}
```

Comment: @prashantrana I declined your edit since a tuple is actually the wrong data structure here (even if it's what the OP requested as output)

Answer (score 0):

here is solution (if you don't mind the solution  in more elaborate way)

```
d1={}
d2={}
d1[1] = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
d1[2] = {'a': 11, 'b': 21}
d2[1] = {'b': 10, 'a': 20}
d2[2] = {'b': 21, 'a': 19}

d4={}

for o in d1.keys():
    d3=[]
    for b in d2[o].keys():
        if d1[o][b] != d2[o][b]:
               d3.append({b: d2[o][b]})
    d4.update({o:tuple(d3)})
print(d4) # require solution.
# print {1: ({'b': 10}, {'a': 20}), 2: ({'a': 19},)}
```

in your code you forgot to add/update the inner values .